# Issues running Hello World Example InsertWithBatchWriter on Accumulo 2.0 in UNO installation

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

I am slowly learning Accumulo command and am running into issues running the Apache Hello World Example to batch ingest 10K rows (50K entries) into accumulo.  https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/examples/

I used the uno build to get my HDFS, zookeeper and Accumulo (2.0) up and running.  I can connect to hadoop and Accumulo using web browser.  I can logon to Accumulo through shell and have successfully created the table hellotable.  The instructions from the Apache example then say to launch the Java program that bulk inserts with a BatchWriter.  The generic example command is as follows:

```
$ ./bin/accumulo org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithBatchWriter instance zookeepers username password hellotable
```

with my installed information, I am running the following command:

My instance of Accumulo is uno  my user name is root and the password is secret

```
$ accumulo org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithBatchWriter uno zookeepers root secret hellotable
```

When I run the command I get following JAVA and accumulo related errors:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/bob/fluo-uno/install/accumulo-2.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/bob/fluo-uno/install/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Invalid argument: Java <main class> 'org.apache.accumulo.examples.simple.helloworld.InsertWithBatchWriter' was not found.  Please use the wholly qualified package name.
```

How can I modify the command to execute cleanly?

Thanks

Comment: Exception is thrown by Accumulo because it cannot find class. Example uses `./bin/accumulo`. You call using `accumulo` - it seems you changed current directory to be `bin` - I think it is why it cannot find class.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the suggestion.  When I run the command with ./bin it just comes back with
   bash: ./bin/accumulo: No such file or directory

I think this is more of a JAVA issue than an Accumulo issue.  I have the overall JAVA package from Apache loaded into the same directory I am running the Accumulo command from.  Do I need to import the JAVA pachage somewhere else, like my .bashrc  ??

Comment: you should go up one level with `cd ..` so `bin` becomes subfolder

Answer (score 0):

The examples you are trying are specifically for Accumulo version 1.7 (as indicated by the URL), which previously shipped with an examples jar on the default class path. However, you have indicated you are running Accumulo 2.0.

Those examples are not written for 2.0, and the examples were moved to a separate repository, and will not be on the Accumulo class path out of the box. The updated example code can be found at https://github.com/apache/accumulo-examples if you wish to try, though I do not know how ready for mainstream use that code is.

You can also try the [tour](https://accumulo.apache.org/tour/) on the website.

Comment: Thanks Christopher that gives me a new set of instructions to digest.  I will dig through the examples for Accumulo 2.0 and work on getting that working.

Comment: I am having issues getting the accumulo-examples for 2.0 to run with my UNO built instance. I will post a separate question with a breakout of the instructions.

Comment: I got the accumulo-examples  to run successfully.  Using an instance built through UNO eliminated the need to change any of the configuration file.  Just had to clone the repository into the accumulo directory and then copy the accumulo-example.jar file into the /lib/ext folder.  This is explained in the instruction in the link above.  I ran helloworld script to insert 50K records into accumulo instance.  Now I need to find a container to interface with the accumulo instance to read the records out, possibly using the accumulo API.  I will post a separate question on containers and accumulo.

Comment: @Woody While I do try to catch questions regarding Accumulo on StackOverflow, a better place to ask your questions is on the Accumulo mailing list. Accumulo is a niche software project, and more Accumulo developers probably monitor that than would see your questions here. It's also good, in general, to engage directly with an open source community with your questions, if one is available, than to post an a third-party forum like this.

Comment: Thanks Christopher,  I will check out the Accumulo mailing list.